# Align Thumb of React Range Slider so it doesn't go outside bounding box

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to make a range slider & I want to make the thumb (indigo) not go outside the bounding box border (red).

[image: align thumb of range slider]

If the thumb is small, then it looks perfect but if the thumb is big, which it is in my case, then it looks out of alignment.

I am using React & Tailwind with the help of [react-range](https://github.com/tajo/react-range) library & the code looks like:

```
import * as React from "react"
import { Range } from "react-range"

export default function App() {
    const [values, setValues] = React.useState([50])

    return (
        <div className="w-full flex justify-center">
            <div className="w-48 border-4 border-red-300">
                <h1 className="text-4xl">Range</h1>
                <label>Slider</label>
                <Range
                    step={1}
                    min={0}
                    max={75}
                    values={values}
                    onChange={(values) => {
                        setValues(values)
                    }}
                    renderTrack={({ props, children }) => (
                        <div
                            {...props}
                            className="w-full h-3 pr-2 my-4 bg-gray-200 rounded-md"
                        >
                            {children}
                        </div>
                    )}
                    renderThumb={({ props }) => (
                        <div
                            {...props}
                            className="w-5 h-5 transform translate-x-10 bg-indigo-500 rounded-full focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500"
                        />
                    )}
                />
                <span>{values[0]}px</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I have also made a reproducible demo → https://codesandbox.io/s/react-tailwind-align-range-slider-ghyf0?file=/src/App.tsx

I want the thumb to be in alignment with `Slider` & `0px` otherwise it looks off. Even the native range slider doesn't go outside the bounding box. How can I achieve that effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [react-slider](https://github.com/zillow/react-slider) instead that remains inside the bounding box.

```
import * as React from "react"
import { Range } from "react-range"
import ReactSlider from "react-slider"

export default function App() {
    const [values, setValues] = React.useState([0])
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0)

    return (
        <div className="w-full flex justify-center">
            <div className="w-48 border-4 border-red-300">
                <h1 className="text-4xl">Range</h1>
                <label>React Range</label>
                <Range
                    step={1}
                    min={0}
                    max={75}
                    values={values}
                    onChange={(values) => {
                        setValues(values)
                    }}
                    renderTrack={({ props, children }) => (
                        <div
                            {...props}
                            className="w-full h-3 pr-2 my-4 bg-gray-200 rounded-md"
                        >
                            {children}
                        </div>
                    )}
                    renderThumb={({ props }) => (
                        <div
                            {...props}
                            className="w-5 h-5 transform translate-x-10 bg-indigo-500 rounded-full focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500"
                        />
                    )}
                />
                <span>{values[0]}px</span>
                <br />
                <br />
                <hr />
                <br />
                <label>React Slider</label>
                <ReactSlider
                    step={1}
                    min={0}
                    max={75}
                    className="w-full h-3 pr-2 my-4 bg-gray-200 rounded-md cursor-grab"
                    thumbClassName="absolute w-5 h-5 cursor-grab bg-indigo-500 rounded-full focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 -top-2px"
                    value={value}
                    onChange={(value: any) => {
                        setValue(value)
                    }}
                />
                <span>{value}px</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The positioning is little off on Codesandbox but it works on my app by giving a little bit of absolute positioning :)

Codesandbox → https://codesandbox.io/s/react-tailwind-align-range-slider-ghyf0?file=/src/App.tsx

[image: react-slider]

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue and I found this hacky solution.

In my case, thumb size is 16 x 16px with 2px track height.

```
const SliderTrack = styled.div`
    height: 2px;
    width: calc(100% - 16px);
    align-self: center;
    position: relative;

    &::before {
      content: '';
      display: inherit;
      height: 2px;
      width: 8px;
      transform: translate(-8px, 2px);
      background-color: 'red';
      z-index: -1;
    }

    &::after {
      content: '';
      display: inherit;
      height: 2px;
      width: 8px;
      transform: translate(8px, -2px);
      background-color: 'green';
      z-index: -1;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
    }
`;
```